# I'm having some issue with arithmetic operators in string

Tags: c++

I am a beginner and I am practicing C++ on UVa.

**Problem link: [P458](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=16&page=show_problem&problem=399)**

My IDE is showing an error in line 15 `decoded = decoded + (s[i] - 7);`

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    while (cin >> s)
    {
        string decoded;
        int len = s.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            decoded = decoded + (s[i] - 7);  //15 no line
        }
        cout << decoded << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I write the line like this `decoded += (s[i] - 7);` it shows no error.

Please explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's recommended to include the error message into the question itself.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you want the code to do when you write that?

Comment: Ok sir, I will mind it.

Comment: [edit] this question to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please explain why this is happening?

`std::string` has a method overload [std::string::operator+=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) that accepts type `char`. That what makes this line:

```
decoded += (s[i] - 7);
```

to compile. But when you write:

```
decoded = decoded + (s[i] - 7);
```

that requires `(s[i] - 7)` to be implicitly converted to `std::string` or something that [std::operator+](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) overload to accept. Simplest solution is to create a temporary string:

```
decoded = decoded + std::string( 1, s[i] - 7);
```

or just use `operator+=` which works as intended. Or even simpler is to modify `s` in place:

```
string s;
while (cin >> s)
{
    for( char &c : s ) c-=7;
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `(s[i] - 7)` which is an `int` to `std::string`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    while (cin >> s)
    {
        string decoded;
        int len = s.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            decoded = decoded + std::to_string((s[i] - 7));  //15 no line
        }
        cout << decoded << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which is usually but not always what the op wants.

Comment: A simple `char` cast should be enough for C++11 and up

Comment: @Harry sir, but it is showing int output when I use it ```decoded = decoded + std::to_string((s[i] - 7));```

Comment: then I think you need to look at what @scohe001 commented. Can you share the input and expected output information